# How to pass `C-u` to `helm-M-x` in `ansi-term` buffer?

Tags: helm, ansi-term

In `ansi-term` buffer, I try to run a command with `C-u` through `helm-M-x`. But it seems doesn't work.

Here's the key sequence I have tried:

```
`C-x M-x <type the cmd> C-u <RET>
```

But it seems the command does not run the way it should with `C-u`.

Comment: Please tell us which command.

Comment: There is only one way to pass prefix argument (including `C-u` of course) to a command within a `helm-M-x` session, no matter which buffer you invoke `helm-M-x` from. In my opinion: 1) while using default `M-x`, you thought you were using `helm-M-x` 2) the keybinding in `ansi-term` buffer is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, I just try to use `C-c C-h k` to find out what's the keybinding for `ansi-term` mode. But when I just type `C-c C-h`, it pops up the `*help*` buffer and luckily shows the keybinding for `helm-M-x` which is bind to `C-c c M-x` or `C-x c M-x`.

What that extra `c` key stroke, the `C-u` is passed to `helm-M-x` properly.

So the solution for me is:

```
`C-c c M-x <cmd supports C-u> C-u`
```

or

```
`C-x c M-x <cmd supports C-u> C-u`
```

I haven't figure out how the keys are binding in that way. Hope it also works for anyone else.

IMO: The keybinding of `term.el` is a little bit chaos.

Answer (score 0):

`C-x M-x` runs the `execute-extended-command` command (the built-in `M-x`), not `helm-M-x`.  With `helm-mode` enabled, `execute-extended-command` looks like `helm-M-x`, but they are very different, the latter provides much more features.

You can define a key, for example `M-x` (`C-x M-x` will not work, I don't know why), for `helm-M-x` in `term-mode`, something like

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-x") #'helm-M-x)))
```

so now `M-x some-command C-u RET` should work.

Comment: This provides some information about a possible confusion for the OP, but it does not answer the question, which is how to pass `C-u` to `helm-M-x`. Consider elaborating this answer or changing it to a comment.

Comment: The OP knows how to pass `C-u` to `helm-M-x` according to his description, but he just doesn't know he is not using `helm-M-x`.

Comment: If you are sure of that then consider editing the question, which asks explicitly "*How to pass `C-u` to `helm-M-x` in `ansi-term` buffer?*".

Comment: @xuchunyang, I have `(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)` in my config file. So that's why I assume `C-x M-x` should call `helm-M-x`.

Comment: @EnzoChi I don't use `ansi-term`, and I'm not know why `C-x M-x` in `ansi-term` buffer should be the same as the `M-x` key, even though you think so, you should then know you are not using `helm-M-x` (see the mode line, `*helm M-x*` v.s. `*helm-mode-execute-extended-command*`) and you will not ask what's wrong with `helm-M-x`.